# tabbed matplotlib plots: QGuiApplication::font() error

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I use [this convenient class](https://github.com/superjax/plotWindow/blob/master/plotWindow.py) to **plot several tabbed plots within the same matplotlib window**.

It works amazingly but makes Python crash after the second window creation with error `QGuiApplication::font(): no QGuiApplication instance and no application font set`. Minimal working example:

```
from plotWindow import plotWindow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for n in range(3):
    pw = plotWindow()
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
    for i in range(1,3):
        f = plt.figure()
        ysin = np.sin(i*x)
        plt.plot(x, ysin, '--')
        pw.addPlot(str(i), f)
    pw.show()
```

I know very little about PyQt5, so I do not really know where to look for. Thank you for you help!

P.S.: For the sake of completeness: here is the full code of the class:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
import sys


class plotWindow():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QMainWindow()
        self.MainWindow.__init__()
        self.MainWindow.setWindowTitle("plot window")
        self.canvases = []
        self.figure_handles = []
        self.toolbar_handles = []
        self.tab_handles = []
        self.current_window = -1
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.MainWindow.resize(1280, 900)
        self.MainWindow.show()

    def addPlot(self, title, figure):
        new_tab = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        new_tab.setLayout(layout)

        figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.05, right=0.99, bottom=0.05, top=0.91, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
        new_canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
        new_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(new_canvas, new_tab)

        layout.addWidget(new_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(new_toolbar)
        self.tabs.addTab(new_tab, title)

        self.toolbar_handles.append(new_toolbar)
        self.canvases.append(new_canvas)
        self.figure_handles.append(figure)
        self.tab_handles.append(new_tab)

    def show(self):
        self.app.exec_()
```

This issue has been reported (but not answered) [here](https://github.com/superjax/plotWindow/issues/7).

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: There is no Traceback, python just exits with this message:
`QGuiApplication::font(): no QGuiApplication instance and no application font set.`

Comment: if you don't see any error message when you run it in console/terminal then it hard to say what can make problem. You may use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it called `"print debugging"` - and maybe it will show where and what can makes problem. Other idea is to search this text in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-lm&q=QGuiApplication%3A%3Afont%28%29%3A+no+QGuiApplication+instance+and+no+application+font+set) (or in Stackoverflow) and maybe someone had the same problem and he found solution

Comment: I did search on google and stackoverflow and tried a few things, but I did not find anything helpful (or I did not understand it). So I'm still at the same point, which is why I decided to post a minimal "not-working" example and ask on the forum

Comment: I get the same error on Linux. You could use `print debugging` to find out which line of code makes problem. And this information can be also useful when you report issue. It is good if you show all details in question in report, and in question on Stackoverflow

Comment: I start removing some parts of code to see when it will work - this way I can find element which makes problem. And I see two problems. (1) when I remove loop which creates figures then I get `QApplication::exec: Please instantiate the QApplication object first`. I think `QMainWindow` wasn't invented to run it many times in the same process. Normally scripts runs only one `QMainWindow` - and maybe it runs some elements which normally are killed when you exit script. But in loop I needed `del pn` and `time.sleep(2)` so `PyQt` has time to remove previous `QMainWindow`.

Comment: (2) when I use `for i in range(1,3): f = plt.figure()` even without `plot()` and `pn.addPlot()` then it starts showing error `QGuiApplication::font()` and maybe it has similar problem - maybe when it removes previous figure then it remove also current object and it has problem to use it - but this can be bigger problem in `PyQt`. So both problems means some problems inside `PyQt`. Frankly I would rather create `MainWindow` only once and later replace tabs in this window - but all this depends on if you want to see window all time. Eventually I would try to use `QWidget` to create window.

Comment: BTW: running `self.MainWindow.__init__()` is useless.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! Yes I missed this, the __init__() is useless there :)
The problem is that the way I use it, I have no idea whether I'm gonna need to call the MainWindow again or not (I display filtered coordinates of different points, and then I may be happy with it or proceed to further filtering
[filter](https://github.com/perfanalytics/pose2sim?tab=readme-ov-file#filtering-3d-coordinates) ). So I'd rather find a way to kill the MainWindow for real every time.

Comment: Are you telling me that right now I'm not using QWidget to create a window? Sorry for this naive question, I have never used pyQt so I used this code as a black box...
Or maybe an entirely different approach?

Comment: you use `QMainWindow` which is special window (which has functions to display menu, toolbar, statusbar). But I don't know if using `QWidget` to create window can help. I tested code with different configurations and adding line  f = plt.figure()` starts making problems. It seems it may try to access `PyQt` (`QGuiApplication`) when it was already deleted. I don't know how stop it. I tried to use `del` to remove object from memory but maybe it creates some other object which still run and try to access old window.

Comment: Thank you again for trying! Yes I think I also tried to delete everything, but it did not seem like it worked... It looks a bit buggy indeed. Can you think of any other approach to display plots in tabs?

Comment: one idea is to create one `QApplication` and one `MainWIndow` and run rest of code inside `QApplication` - and it would need to use some button inside window to replace tabs without exiting `QApplication`.